# Position div and move it after a certeain amount of scroll with jquery

Tags: jquery, css, position

I have a absolutely position bottom toolbar. I want it to dissapear when the page is fully scrolled to top and appear back when it is scrolled down.

Exactly the behavior of the share option in this [site](http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/seeking-a-php-ninja-in-los-angeles/). The share bar in the left with twitter and all is only seen once u scroll to its position, but remains there when you scroll further. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do something like this:

```
var $window = $(window),
    minimalVerticalBoxOffset = 200;

$window.scroll(function () {
    yourBox.css('top', Math.max(minimalVerticalBoxOffset, $window.scrollTop()) + 'px');
});
```

This code assumes that `yourBox` is a jQuery selecition containing an absolutely positioned element (which is the one that should be moved around).